# WP_Query for distinct meta values

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to construct a WP_Query in such a way that once a (ACF) meta value exists on a post in the query the subsequent ones cannot contain this value?

For instance if I'm querying `countries`, then after the first post containing `France` on that field none of the next ones in the query will contain France? And once I get Spain neither France nor Spain can be in the next? etc. etc.

I know how to solve this by checking for value-existence inside the loop, I'm trying to create a performant and succinct query :)

Comment: Can't you just exclude posts with the `countries` meta set as `france`? Or do you want to include the first post set with `france` in your query? I'm not sure it's possible to do this in the query.

Comment: @joshmoto No, as described I only want to exclude France after I've gotten a post with that value. Same for Spain, Mexico, Greece, whatever.